Traceid is coming different for every microservice call
I'm using webclient for making service call, but the traceid is coming different for every call.
I am expecting that the parent traceid should be the same to the child microservice call. I am using micrometer as sleuth is not supported by springboot 3.

Did you inject WebClient.Builder and created the WebClient from this builder? Otherwise you need to set the observationRegistry and observationConvention yourself.

webClient.get()
.uri("http://localhost:8083/api/organization/"+emp.getOrganizationCode())
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(OrganizationDto.class)
.block();
this is what I'm doing

Please check the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/observability.html#observability.http-client.webclient
You need to create WebClient using the Builder that Spring provides to you:
@Bean
WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder.baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/api").build();
}

Here's a sample app: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-samples/tree/main/webclient
(Fyi: you shouldn't call block.)
